# Expanding the table rows using html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, html-table

I have created a 3 level of expand and collapse table using html. But, the expanded rows is going upwards it has to be displayed below. I mean, it has to be expanded one below the other. Kindly help me to resolve this issue.
It needs to look like below:
I have created a 3 level of expand and collapse table using html. But, the expanded rows is going upwards it has to be displayed below. I mean, it has to be expanded one below the other. Kindly help me to resolve this issue. It needs to look like below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GIKf.png)

```js
$("tbody > tr:not([data-level='3'])").addClass("expandable sign folded");
$("tbody > tr:not([data-level='1'])").hide();
$("tbody > tr")
    .css("padding-left", function (index) {
    return 10 * parseInt($(this).data("level"), 10) + "px";
});

function range(lowEnd, highEnd) {
    // assert lowEnd >= 0 and highEnd < 100
    var validation = (lowEnd <= highEnd) && (lowEnd >= 0) && (highEnd < 100);
    if (!(validation)) {
        console.assert(validation, 
                       'Function "range" received unlikely values: ' +
                       lowEnd + ' and ' + highEnd + "...");
    } else {
        var arr = [];
        while (lowEnd <= highEnd) {
            arr.push(lowEnd++);
        }
        return arr;
    }
}

function name_range(fun, lowEnd, highEnd) {
    var arr = range(lowEnd, highEnd);
    jQuery.each(arr, function (index, value) {
        arr[index] = fun(value);
    });
    return arr;
}

function create_selector(level) {
    return "[data-level='" + level + "']";
}

$("tr.expandable").click(function () {
    var this_level = parseInt($(this).data("level"), 10);
    var this_level_selector = create_selector(this_level);
    var next_level_selector = create_selector(this_level + 1);
    var next_or_lower = name_range(create_selector,
    this_level + 1, 10); // TODO: find last level
    var this_or_higher = name_range(create_selector, 0, this_level);
    var node = $(this).prevUntil(this_or_higher.join(","));
    // different behaviour according to state (expanded / folded):
    if ($(this).hasClass("expanded")) {
        $(this).removeClass("expanded").addClass('folded');
        $(node).not("expanded").removeClass("expanded").addClass('folded');
        $(node).filter(next_or_lower.join(",")).hide();
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("expanded").removeClass('folded');
        $(node).filter(next_level_selector).show();
    }
});
```

```css
table, tr, td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-color: gray;
}
tr:not([data-level='3']) {
    cursor:pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
}
tr.expanded .sign:after {
    content:"-";
}
tr.folded .sign:after {
    content:"+";
}
td:first-child {
    padding: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body> 
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Title</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
<tbody>
<tr data-level='3'>
<td>contractor 1</td>                               <td>18798736</td>                                         
</tr>
<tr data-level='2'>                                       <td>Sup two<span class="sign"></span>
</td>                                         <td>18796789</td>                                         
</tr>
<tr data-level='2'>                                     <td>Sup one</td>                                     <td>18796789</td>                                      
</tr>
<tr data-level='1'>                                     <td>Main<span class="sign"></span>
</td>                                             <td>18798736</td>                                
</tr>
```

Comment: The html is obviously set up in wrong order. Why is that if you want the opposite?

Comment: Change the order of the `tr` rows and change `prevUntil` to `nextUntil`.  What's the issue?